# CoreAnimation fades out layers and moves a copy instead of just moving the layer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-animation

I am working on a view that displays a grid of core animation layers. When I remove a layer I want that layer to fade out and have the other layers move to fill the gap. This almost works the way I want it to using implicit animations. The only problem is that the layers that should move fade out while a copy of those layers move to the new position. How can I change that behavior so that layers just move instead of move and fade?

To remove a single layer I just do `[theLayer removeFromSuperLayer]` and then call my layout routine on the container layer which does this:

```
CGFloat x = 0;
CGFloat y = CGRectGetMaxY( [layer bounds] ) - buttonHeight - buttonVPadding;
for (CALayer *l in [layer sublayers]) {
    if ([layer bounds].size.width < x + buttonWidth) {
        x = 0;
        y -= buttonHeight + buttonVPadding;
    }
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight );
    [l setBounds: bounds];
    [l setPosition: CGPointMake( x, y )];
    x += buttonWidth + buttonVPadding;
}
```

I tried overriding the default animation behavior in `- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event;` but I couldn’t find out which events to override to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After typing this question and thinking some more about the problem I found a solution or workaround. Instead of directly removing a layer I set it to hidden and skip hidden layers in my layout loop. Then after all the animations are done (in the completion block of my `CATransaction`) I remove all the hidden layers without animation.

Answer (score 0):

as Far as I understand about CAAnimation, the key argument identifies the CALayer property you are animating. in your case this should be bounds and position.

you are also, overall, modifying the sublayers property, since you are removing one layer.

So those three keys are what you have to play with.

On the other hand, by defining your delegate actionForKey, you should have the chance to see for which keys this method is called. or you could inspect the actions dictionary in your CALayer. but I don't know if it helps.